# spring batch compositeitemwriter not rolling back

Tags: transactions, spring-batch

I have a compositeItemWriter that has 2 delegate writers :
1. HeaderWriter to write some fields from my object to Header Table
2. DetailWriter to write fileds to a detail table.

Issue is, when an exception occurs in DetailWriter, data is not getting rolled back from the Headerwriter. Looks like data is being updated in 2 different transactions.
How do I enforce data integrity by having both updates in the same transaction ?

---

FYI, I am using Informix and had to extend some of the Spring batch classes to 
get Spring working on Informix.

My configuration is as follows :

Section from my reportjob.xml :

```
<bean id="programHeaderWriter"   
class="com.bah.discrepancy.writer.ProgramHeaderWriter">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />  
    <property name="itemSqlParameterSourceProvider">
    <bean   
 class="com.bah.discrepancy.parametermapper.ProgramHdrParameterMapper"/>
    </property>
 </bean>
<bean id="programDetailWriter"  
class="com.bah.discrepancy.writer.ProgramDetailWriter">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />  
    <property name="itemSqlParameterSourceProvider">
    <bean 
 class="com.bah.discrepancy.parametermapper.ProgramDetailParamMapper" />
    </property>
 </bean>
```

Context.xml :

```
<bean id="transactionManager"       
class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransaction
    Manager" />

<bean id="batchDefaultSerializer"  
class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.
DefaultExecutionContextSerializer" />

<bean id="dataSource"  
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver"
         />
        <property name="url" value="<URL>" />
        <property name="username" value="<UserID>" />
        <property name="password" value="<Password>" />
    </bean>



    <bean id="jobRepository"  
     class="com.bah.batch.informixsupport.InformixJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="databaseType" value="Informix"/>
        <property name="incrementerFactory" ref="informixIncrementer"/>
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
        <property name="tablePrefix" value="BATCH_" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: Can you share your configuration?

Answer (score 0):

hope this is resolved by this time for sure. But just wanted to check if you have fixed the issue in the following way or any other way?

[Spring Batch CompositeItemWriter Transaction Roll back issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33603933/spring-batch-compositeitemwriter-transaction-roll-back-issue)